# Child Fragments recreated on Back Press in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, back-stack, android-nested-fragment

As per my requirement for app I have added Child Fragments inside **MainFragment**, which extends Fragment like below code dynamically on conditions after getting server response:

```
DetailsImageFragment imgFragment = DetailsImageFragment.newInstance();
FragmentTransaction ft = getChildFragmentManager()
.beginTransaction();
ft.add(R.id.thisFragmentLayout, imgFragment).commit();
```

Everything works fine but when I call other fragment from this fragment with `replace()` by another fragment as follows:

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
SecondFragment categoryFragment = SecondFragment.newInstance();
fm.beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.contentFrame, categoryFragment).addToBackStack(null)
    .commit();
```

It well replaces this second Fragment.

But when I press Back Button, *MainFragment* reloads all Child Fragments again. With this, I am facing a performance issue on back visit. It's taking a lot of time to reload previous *MainFragment*.
Can any one help me out of this issue? Your help will be appreciate.